# Gitlab: import project from other server via SSH add key to known hosts?

Tags: gitlab

When importing a project in Gitlab web-interface from `ssh://git@example.com/example`
I get the error `Host key verification failed.`

I logged in on the Gitlab server directly via SSH and added the host to the known hosts and verified it by running a successful `git clone`.

Still the error persists in the web-interface clone process. Is there a way to add the host key to gitlab?

Comment: For other searchers: Importing from ssh is reserved to Gitlab EE

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you added the known host to the correct account?  It will probably need to be some kind of service account.  Or maybe you should add to the /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts?